# onsubmit function don't work

Tags: javascript, html, django-1.8

i want to verify my form value on submit, but it move directly to the action without executing the function onsubmit, can anyone please help me.
here is my html page:

```
...
<script src="{% static 'js/formulaire.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function isValide(){
 var resultat = true
 if (!isAlpha(document.getElementById('titre').value) ||   document.getElementById('titre').value == "" {
   resultat = false:
   document.getElementById('titre').className="inp-form-error";
   document.getElementById('err1').style.display="block";
   document.getElementById('err2').style.display="block";
 }
 else {
   document.getElementById('titre').className="inp-form";
   document.getElementById('err1').style.display="none";
   document.getElementById('err2').style.display="none";
 }
 if (!isFloat(document.getElementById('seuil').value) ||   document.getElementById('seuil').value == "" {
   resultat = false:
   document.getElementById('seuil').className="inp-form-error";
   document.getElementById('err3').style.display="block";
   document.getElementById('err4').style.display="block";
 }
 else {
   document.getElementById('seuil').className="inp-form";
   document.getElementById('err3').style.display="none";
   document.getElementById('err4').style.display="none";
 }
 return resultat;
}
</script>
...
<form id="notif-form" name="form1" action="{% url 'mgmt_notif:verif_notif' %}" method="POST" onsubmit="return isValide();">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="id-form" >
            <tr>
                    <th valign="top">Titre :</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="nom_notif" id="titre" class="inp-form" /></td>
                    <td>
                    <div id="err1" class="error-left"></div>
                    <div id="err2" class="error-inner">Verifier ce champs.</div>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <th valign="top">Seuil :</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="rate" id="seuil" class="inp-form" /></td>
                    <td>
                    <div id="err3" class="error-left"></div>
                    <div id="err4" class="error-inner">Verifier ce champs</div>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <th valign="top">Description :</th>
                    <td colspan=2><textarea name="desc_notif" class="form-textarea"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <td valign="top">
                    <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="form-submit" />
                    <input type="reset" value="Annuler" class="form-reset"  />
            </td>
            <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

and the formulaire.js file:

```
function isTel(valeurChamp){

    var pattern = /^0[\d]{9}$/;

    return pattern.test(valeurChamp);

}
function isAlpha(valeurChamp){

    var pattern = /^[a-zéç| èùâëïöüâêûî\-\s]+$/i;

    return pattern.test(valeurChamp);

}
function isMail(valeurChamp){

    var pattern = /^[-+.\w]{1,64}@[-.\w]{1,64}\.[-.\w]{2,6}$/;

    return pattern.test(valeurChamp);

}
function isFloat(valeurChamp){

    var pattern = /^{0,1}d*.{0,1}d+$/;

    return pattern.test(valeurChamp);
}
function isPassword(p1,p2) {
  if (p1.value == '' || p2.value == '') {
   return false;
  }
  else if (p1.value != p2.value) {
   return false;
  }
  else if (p1.value != p2.value) {
   return true;
  }
  else {
   return false;
  }
}
```

and thank

Comment: Remove onsubmit function call from form tag and add onclick on submit button. eg.<input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="form-submit" onclick="return isValide();" />

Comment: I try it but still not working

Comment: May be these are typos while posting the question over here, but would like to get you noticed some mistakes in isValide() like :

# Semicolon missing (var resultat = true).
# colon(:) used in many lines instead of semicolon (;) e.g. while changing values of variable resultat to false.

Comment: There are few issues with your js code. just keep an alert before var resultat = true and after resultat = false: line and check whether both alerts are fired